# How to access value from one page to another in asp.net using sql

Tags: asp.net

Good day may i please get help,am currently looking for a way of accessing value from one page to another using asp.net sql language

Answer (score 1):

You can do in following ways:

**1. Response.Redirect**

*Page1.aspx*

```
Response.Redirect("test.aspx?Name="+t.Text);
```

*Page2.aspx*

```
if (Request.QueryString["Name"]!= null)
    Label3.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"];
```

**2.Cookies**

```
HttpCookie cook = new HttpCookie("Name");
cook.Value = txtName.Text; 
Response.Cookies.Add(cook); 
Response.Redirect("WebForm5.aspx");
```

*Page 2*

```
if (Request.Cookies["cook "] != null )
    Label3.Text = Request.Cookies["cook "].Value;
```

**3.Session**

```
Session["ses"] = txtName.Text; 
Response.Redirect("WebForm5.aspx");
```

*Page 2*

```
if(Session["ses"] != null) 
    Label3.Text = Session["ses"].ToString();
```

Comment: Am still gonna try it but i thank you for assist god bless and if am stacked i'll come back to you for more clarity